# particle distribution with texture does only work in viewport

Tags: particles, error, instances

[image: render in viewport]I want to distribute trees on a landscape (with a particle system) based on a texture. In the particle settings I chose the texture I wanted to use, and checked "Density" below the influence tab in the texture properties. It works fine in the viewport, however, as soon as I render it, all the trees are suddenly evenly distributed.

Rendered View[image: ][1]]

Comment: Have you tried weight painting?

Comment: Yes, weight painting works as expected, but there are many mountains in this landscape, which I don't want to paint out manually, especially when I have the exact texture already. Mabie there is some way of importing the texture as a weight paint map?